# UICollisionBehavior: Rolling Ball?

Tags: ios, uikit-dynamics, uicollisionbehavior

I am trying to work on an iOS iPhone app that uses UIKit Dynamics in order to do the physics animation. It's a basketball game where you can throw the ball into the hoop. However, I can't figure out how to make the ball circular (treated this way by the `UICollisionBehavior` and `UIDynamicAnimator`)?

I've tried: `ball.layer.cornerRadius = ball.frame.size.width / 2.0;`

But this only draws the ball circular. It doesn't actually behave this way. I also know I can draw boundaries using: `addBoundaryWithIdentifier:forPath:`

But I can't figure out how to put bounds around a `UIView` (`UIImageView` in my case) that aren't just a rectangle? I know I could do this using SpriteKit, but I've already written a few hours of code for the basketball game using UIKit Dynamics and don't want to switch over if there is a simple fix. Thank you!

Comment: UIKit Dynamics doesn't do arbitrary shapes -- as you've noted, Sprite Kit is the API you should use for game animations.

Answer (score 3):

In `iOS 9` you can now do exactly what you want.

In your `UIView` subclass you can add this:

```
- (UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsType)collisionBoundsType
{
    return UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsTypeEllipse;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it using `UIKit Dynamics`. `UIDynamicItem` protocol implementation requires the object that implements the protocol to provide a `bounds` property which is a `CGRect`.

You have to go for `SpriteKit`.